# Can we expose Apache Pulsar metrics through Micrometer?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer, apache-pulsar

The broker metrics are exposed under "/metrics/" at port 8080. But, what about the client metrics (both consumer and producer)? Can we expose Apache Pulsar metrics through Micrometer (particularly with Prometheus)?

It would be interesting if we are using Pulsar with Spring Boot. I'm not using the Spring for Apache Pulsar framework. The client metrics would be like: how long it takes to consume a batch, how many failures, etc.

Comment: Did you have a look at this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#micrometer ?

Comment: I'm not using the Spring for Apache Pulsar framework

Comment: You might want to ask the Pulsar team to add support here: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/20845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO `Apache Pulsar` does not have built-in support for exposing client [metrics](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/next/reference-metrics/)  directly through Micrometer` or any other specific metrics system

Although `Pulsar` does not have native integration with `Micrometer`, you can instrument your Pulsar client code to collect metrics and then use `Micrometer` to export those metrics to `Prometheus`.

use the `Pulsar client API's` built-in mechanisms for tracking performance, failures, etc. e.g.  can use `timers` to measure the time it takes to consume a batch and counters to track the number of failures. Once you have collected the metrics in your `Pulsar client code`, you can push them to `Micrometer's registry`, and Micrometer will expose them to `Prometheus`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI the Pulsar Go client exposes metrics out of the box (with a little code)

Here is a list of the metrics
https://github.com/apache/pulsar-client-go/blob/master/pulsar/internal/metrics.go

See here for integration options
https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.1.x/client-libraries-go-use/